# How to know the name of the system call that I'm currently handling?

Tags: linux-kernel, stack-trace, system-calls

I'm trying to debugging SELinux by printing some information in the `avc_audit()` function. The information that I need is the current pid and system call. The pid is easy: `get_current()->pid`, but I can't find a way to get the current system call that I'm handling.

I have looked at `get_wchan()`, but it only works with waiting processes. I could examine the stack just like what `get_wchan()` does, but it there a better way?

Comment: Call `dump_stack()` in your code, this will give you the stack trace into the syslog, this should help you determine which syscall was invoked. There are better ways to trace syscall in the kernel, `systemtap`, `ftrace` etc. you may want try those ?

Comment: @askb, Seems to be a good starting point to dig in. I thought the system call number should be saved somewhere, rather than digging into the stack trace.

Comment: This patch does exactly what I want, but it didn't manage to get into mainline. "[C/R ARM][PATCH 1/3] ARM: Rudimentary syscall interfaces" http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2010-March/011812.html It's interesting to read the discussions.

Answer (score 2):

Call dump_stack() in your code, this will give you the stack trace into the syslog, this should help you determine which syscall was invoked. There are better ways to trace syscall in the kernel, systemtap, ftrace etc. You may want to start off looking into [process/strace.stp](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/#process/strace.stp)